# iOS - How to Detect if Button is Pressed Twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a button that you can press and the text of that button will change. I want to be able to detect when the user clicks the button again, so that the button text will change back to its original text. How would I be able to do that? Here is the code I have so far.

```
//Set Text and alignment for the buttons

[nocavities setTitle:@"No cavities\n5 points" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
nocavities.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

-(IBAction)nocavitiesaction:(id)sender {

[sender setTitle:@"Whenever you visit our office cavity-free, you will receive 5 points!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I feel like in the IBAction I should change the state to

```
UIControlStateNormalPressed
```

but I'm not sure.

Comment: Just use a state variable... or a click counter... and if counter > 1 && counter % 2 == 0, then it was clicked twice (or multiples of 2)

Comment: Would you mind showing me some example code, as I am new to the developing community.

Comment: @guarabrazo beat me to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a counter inside the `IBAction`

Something like this:

```
-(IBAction)nocavitiesaction:(id)sender {

    static int count = 0;
    count ++;
    if(count % 2 != 0){
        //Set title 1
    }else{
        //Set title 2
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work since you're setting count to 0 at the start of the method and thus count will always == 1 going into the conditional.

Comment: Making it static prevents that behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open xib file and select the button.
2. Under the attributes inspector you will find "State Config", select "Default" from dropdown.
3. Change the title of button to "No cavities\n5 points"
4. Change State Config to "Selected"
5. Change title to "Whenever you visit our office cavity-free, you will receive 5 points!"
6. Now toggle these titles by.

   ```
   - (IBAction)nocavitiesaction:(id)sender
   {
       UIButton * button = sender;
       button.selected = !button.selected;
   }
   ```

Comment: Actually, I like your answer best. I'm going to update mine to change the title for state programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

like this.
declare global int flag=1;

```
-(IBAction)methodName:(id)sender
{
     if(flag==1)
     {
         //set title 1
          flag=2;
     }
     else
     {
        //set  title 2
        flag=1
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `UIControlStateNormalPressed` state, but there is a `UIControlStateSelected`. You can set a title for both the selected and normal states, then manually set the `UIButton` to its selected state like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.button setTitle:@"Whenever you visit our office cavity-free, you will receive 5 points!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setTitle:@"No cavities\n5 points" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
- (IBAction)nocavitiesaction:(UIButton*)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Note: I've changed the parameter from `id` to `UIButton` to avoid having to convert `id` to `UIButton` to check its selected state. And the `UIButton` should be of type "Custom" if you'd like to prevent the background tint while selected.

Comment: Why does the highlight of the text become blue?

Comment: @WilliamDayanayev You have to change your button type from "system" to "custom" to disable that behavior.

Comment: @WilliamDayanayev Although you've already accepted an answer, I'd suggest also checking out my updated answer and Umair's similar answer because I think the way we've done it is actually the proper way to accomplish what you're trying to do.